# Should subresource integrity and cross reference always be used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a bout 3 lots of Jquery being used from various CDN's, should I use sub resource integrity on all scripts? Should I also be using it on locally hosted Javascript files? Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

It appears only one uses it, the others don't, would it be advisable to do it for all? I'm also planning on using just 3.4.1 slim.min instead of 3.2.1 and 3.4.1 separately. Thanks.

Comment: You are the only one who can answer this question, for yourself, by answering this one: *"What do you want the browser to do when it loads a resource required by your page, which has been unexpectedly manipulated?"*. Do you want the browser to ignore the resource (use `integrity` and `checksum`) or use it (don't use them)? What's more important to you? The user's security or how the page looks/works? If it's a trusted source (i.e: the resource owner's domain, there's no need for checking). If it's a CDN, it could, theoretically, go rogue, although, arguably, it would be suicidal.

Comment: Right okay...well I suppose the two most important resources, the bootstrap core CSS and the core JQuery are both using integrity. All other resources will be hosted locally, and the other JS is just for a data table so wouldn't cause issues if it did get hacked. What are the downsides to using integrity? Is it slower?

Comment: The time the browser needs to compare the checksum is insignificant. The only downside is that when a resource is modified (a.k.a. never), it gets ignored by browsers (basically the manipulation gets huge visibility at the expense of your website looking broken). As a side note, there are very few cases where loading different versions of jQuery is the right thing to do. Unless you know exactly what you're doing and you're using at least one of them in noConflict mode, you're *Doing-it-wrong™*.

Comment: Haha thanks, I fixed the jquery and am now just using the one version. I am still not quite understanding the issue- if the only time a resource were to be modified would be if it was for malicious intent, then what downside is there to taking this extra precaution?

Comment: There is no danger, man. I haven't advised in any direction. If I would, I'd advise you use them. Discovering an unexpected manipulation at the expense of the website being broken while it's infected is much better than not knowing about it and silently infecting all users for who knows how long. It's just that you (or, to be exact, the website's owner) should be the one who answers this question, not some complete stranger on SO. By all accounts, a programmer knowledgeable enough to make malware is likely to have high rep on [SO], don't you think?

Comment: Thank you for your help...I'm new to all this so wanted a more experienced users opinion on the matter. I think for now I will just use integrity on the more important files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202678/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-s-stevens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For locally hosted js, it would not be suggested to use the subresource integrity if still wanted to use you can use but you need to make u generate hash every time the file changes and update the hash value to the src tag.

For the remaining, you can add but as they are the third party js and we don't know when they would be updated, if we get release notes for them we implement the SRI for those also.

Please check the below which Help having a failover mechanism if the file updates and the hash fails
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/